# How to substitute a certain letter without substituting others?

Tags: python, regex

How to substitute a certain letter in a certain location without substituting the other same letter? For example:

```
text = `"I need help. I need 5.4 dollar."`
```

I tried:

```
a = re.compile('\D(\.)')
print(a.sub('\n',text))
```

However, the output was

```
"I need hel\n I need 5.4 dolla\n"
```

How can I get the output of

```
"I need help\n I need 5.4 dollar\n"
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?<=\D)\.', '\n', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing effective regular expressions starts with formulating what you need really specifically. In your case, it looks like you want to:

"Replace all periods with newline symbols, unless the period is part of a number."

And to make that even more precise, defining what it means that a period is part of a number: it likely means that it is followed directly by a number, so that it matches `5.4`, but also `.4` in `The average score of .4 was low.`, but not `4.` in `She only counted a total of 4.`

"Replace all periods with newline symbols, unless the period is followed immediately by a digit."

```
import re

text = '"I have .5 dollar. I need 5.4 dollar. But they only gave me 3."'

expression = re.compile(r'\.(?!\d)')
print(expression.sub('\n', text))
```

What your example `\D(\.)` matched instead was: "Match a single character that is not a digit, followed by a literal `.`", which is not what you wanted to replace.

The new expressions `\.(?!\d)` matches "Match a literal `.`, but only if it is not followed by a digit." It uses something called negative lookahead, more about that here https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [lookback](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
>>> text = "I need help. I need 5.4 dollar."
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\D)\.', '\n', text)
'I need help\n I need 5.4 dollar\n'
```

In this case `(?<=\D)` is asserting that the character in front of a literal `.` is not a digit.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example, you can use the regex metacharacter \b to match the beginning or end of a word (word boundary)

```
import re

text = "I need help. I need 5.4 dollar."

a = re.compile('\b(\.)')
print(a.sub('\n',text))
```